# This for loop does not iterate through all element in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I wrote a small algorithm which enable me to assign weight to word depending on their position and in order to check their presence in a lexicon. The script loops in a list of element and then for each word retrieve the index and if the word is found in lexicon, the index of the word is multiply by one and if not the value is 0. After all the weight of the word I kept in dictionary and the sum of them are divided by the len of elt.

So far it works but I do not understand why , the loop stop at one element and do not cover the whole lexicon.

Here a sample :

```
lexiconpos =['beau','bel', 'gentil', 'bon', 'généreux']
lexiconneg =['gros', 'laid','méchant']

def find_nearest(texte, liste1, liste2):
    d_neg = {}
    d_pos = {}
    d_0 = {}

    sentences_weight =[]
    for elt in texte:
        print(elt)
        for w in elt.split():
            #print (w, ':')
            pos = elt.split().index(w)
            #print(pos)
            if w in lexiconpos:
                d_pos[w] = pos * 1
                
            elif w in lexiconneg:
                d_neg[w] = pos * 1
            
            else: 
                d_0[w] = 0
        
        mot_weight_pos = sum(d_pos.values()) /  len(elt)
        mot_weight_neg = sum(d_neg.values()) / len(elt)
        print(d_neg)
        print(d_pos)
        print(d_0)
        print(mot_weight_pos)
        print(mot_weight_neg)
    
        if mot_weight_pos > mot_weight_neg:
            return elt, "pos"
        else:
            return elt, "neg"
                
    
     
a = ['tu être beau mais très méchant', 'ta gros tête est laid mais tu es bon et généreux']
find_nearest(a, lexiconpos, lexiconneg)
```

Result : Do not print the other sentence

```
tu être beau mais très méchant
{'méchant': 5}
{'beau': 2}
{'tu': 0, 'être': 0, 'mais': 0, 'très': 0}
0.06666666666666667
0.16666666666666666
('tu être beau mais très méchant', 'neg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is inside the for loop. The function execution is terminated at the first encountered return statement.
Pull the return statements out of the for loop.